# Generating a list of numbers with Haskell

Tags: haskell

A Pythagorean triplet is a set of three natural numbers, a < b < c, for which,
a^(2) + b^(2) = c^(2). There exists exactly one Pythagorean triplet for which a + b + c = 1000.

I am trying to generate a list with the answer:

```
[200,375,425]
```

For that, I programmed in Haskell:

```
p = [ [a, b, c] | b <- [1..1000], a <- [1..b], let c = 1000 - b - a, a^2 + b^2 == c^2 && b<c]
```

This generates

```
[[200,375,425]]
```

How can I change my solution to generate the first output (instead of the one I have now)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
head $ [ [a, b, c] | b <- [1..1000], a <- [1..b], let c = 1000 - b - a, a^2 + b^2 == c^2 && b<c]
```

Answer (score 4):

Look at your output.  It generated a list whose first result is the result you want.  There's a function that takes a list and returns the first element -- `head`.  Call `head` on the output from your existing code, and you will get the result you want.